# How to map the folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file, window

I tried with below command it's not working:

```
@echo off
net use z: /delete
net use z: \\10.87.X.XX\Sserver\Server password /user:domain\username /savecred /p:yes
```

Comment: What is the error message? And are you able to access the server through explorer?

Comment: `net use /?` outputs `/persistent:yes` but not `/p:yes` on Windows 7. Are there any spaces in `password`, `username`, share name `Sserver` or folder name `Server` which requires the entire parameter containing such a string with space do be enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: i have included "" in the path .then it's working.